# How prevent a HTML section tag from scrolling while autocomplete popper is open

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion-js

I am using [Material ui autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#autocomplete-api) in my React app.

With the `PopperComponent` prop and some custom css styling I made the popper `full-width` and fill the `height` of the screen on mobile.

How do I prevent the a certain HTML `<section>` tag from scrolling while autocomplete popper is open?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just give him some className and apply the style on it?

Comment: You can receive it as accepted answer...@meez